# In Objective-C, How Can I Make a Global Configuration That Is Accessible to All?

Tags: ios, objective-c, configuration, global-variables, plist

I am new to Objective-C and iOS development and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Anyway, basically I have a file Configs.plist which, for now has two sets of Keys:Value (Customer:Generic and Short_Code:Default). I want these data to be easily accessible to all classes so I created these:

Configs.h

```
 extern NSString * const CUSTOMER;
 extern NSString * const SHORT_CODE;

 @interface Configs
 + (void)initialize;
 + (NSDictionary *)getConfigs;
 @end
```

Configs.m

```
 #import "Configs.h"

 NSString * const CUSTOMER = @"Customer";
 NSString * const SHORT_CODE = @"Short_Code";

 static NSDictionary *myConfigs;

 @implementation Configs
 + (void)initialize{
     if(myConfigs == nil){
         NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Configs" ofType:@"plist"];
         settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
     }
 }

 + (NSDictionary *)getConfigs{
     return settings;
 }
 @end
```

And on a the test file Test.m:

```
 NSLog(@"Customer: %@", [[Configs getConfigs] objectForKey:CUSTOMER]);
 NSLog(@"Short Code: %@", [[Configs getConfigs] objectForKey:SHORT_CODE]);
```

The thing is, this approach works but I want to know if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is good as long as your configuration does not change during execution. If it does, you're better off with the singleton exposing your config as properties, so you would be able to do something like this:

```
[[Config shared] customer];
[[Config shared] setShortCode:@"CODE"];
```

You could still init the config from the plist, or implement coding protocol to store it in the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't quite understand what you meant but, well, this is one topic I need to read more. Anyway, yes, during the execution the configuration will not be modified. The configuration basically is a pre-build requirement.

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty sure that your config is mutable, so I wanted to give you some insight into how to deal with the mutable config. But if it's static, than I think your solution is very good.